# Specify --no-parallel flag inside Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

According to the documentation http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/up.html vagrant up has optional parameter `--no-parallel`

Is it possible to specify this flag inside of Vagrantfile or at least warn user if it's not specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got an answer from original repo [environment test suite](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/test/unit/vagrant/environment_test.rb):

`ENV['VAGRANT_NO_PARALLEL'] = 'yes'`

**Edit:**

Well, unfortunately, I have to say It's not an option. Seems like option works for env, where `vagrant` is launched, but not in `Vagrantfile`

`$ VAGRANT_NO_PARALLEL=yes vagrant up` - works

`$ vagrant up` with `Vagrantfile` containint `VAGRANT_NO_PARALLEL` - fails

Comment: `ENV['VAGRANT_NO_PARALLEL'] = 'yes'` works fine in my file. Vagrant 1.8.1 with Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765 and `VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"` in my Vagrantfile. I am on Debian Jessie for my host OS.

Comment: Are there any issues in keeping the vagrant in parallel environment?

Comment: @KiranKTelukunta Can't answer that, it was 6 years ago - I can even barely remember what Vagrant does at all :)